# When does the rational predicate yield false in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

When is the `rational?` predicate useful if even `(rational? (sqrt 2))` is true?

I understand that the matter of qualifying numbers rational/irrational is complicated by the fact that numbers are inexactly represented. The predicate is there, anyway.

Comment: There's an example in R7RS: `(rational? -inf.0) => #f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an implementation that uses floating point representation of mathematically irrational numbers, any number other than infinity or NaN will be be rational, since a floating point value is essentially a fraction with a power of 2 as the denominator. Basically, irrational numbers like π and `(sqrt 2)` are actually rational approximations in these systems.

The `rational?` predicate is provided for completeness to allow for other possible representations of irrational numbers, such as continued fractions. I don't think there are any real implementations like this, it's just theoretical.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Could you give us an example, other than `-inf.0`, where `rational?` yields `#f`?

Comment: `+inf.0`, `-inf.0`, `+nan.0` as I said in the answer.

Comment: Well, these don't pop up every day. You mentioned continued fractions.

Comment: AFAIK there aren't any Scheme implementations like that. It's just theoretical.

Answer (score 1):

The `rational?` predicate returns true if a number is a rational: a number of the form n/m where n and m are integers and m is not zero.  That means that, as Barmar says, it must return true for floats (assuming the normal float representation), because floats are, in fact rationals.

But there's a really important case where `rational?` must return false: complex numbers.  Complex numbers are *not* rational numbers.  So for any implementation which has complex numbers, `rational?` will return false for those:

```
> (rational? 1+2i)
#f
> (number? 1+2i)
#t
> (complex? 1+2i)
#t
> (real? 1+2i)
#f
> (exact? 1+2i)
#t
> (complex? 1)
#t
> (rational? 1+0i)
#t
```